# Infinity trigonometric sum

Tags: calculus

I see in a paper about infinity sum a strage sum
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 \sinh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)}{\pi  k^5 \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)-\cosh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  k\right)\right)}=-\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi ^4}{2\ 105}$$
i do not have idea how began maybe euler Mclaurin?

Comment: Poisson summation formula. Again.

Comment: Interésting question Daurizio could you explain how using the poissom fórmula summation in this  particular serie